# Jquery Function Doesn't post ID Value

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following jQuery function:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.addbid', function(){
        var id = "#"+$(this).attr("id");

        $.get(url+"schedules/addbid?id="+$(this).attr("id"),
            function (data) {
                $(id).html(data);
                return false;
        });

        return false;
```

And this is my link to pass the id to the function:

```html
<a id="<?php echo $schedule->id; ?>" class="addbid" href="<?php echo url('/schedules/addbid');?>">Add Bid</a>
```

I'm trying to pass the id to a function inside my module now this is my function:

```php
public function addbid() {
        if (!Auth::LoggedIn())
            return;

        $routeid = $this->get->id;

        if ($routeid == '') {
            echo 'No route passed';
            return;
        }

        $route = SchedulesData::findSchedules(array('s.id' => $routeid));

        if (!is_array($route) && !isset($route[0])) {
            echo 'Invalid Route';
            return;
        }

        CodonEvent::Dispatch('bid_preadd', 'Schedules', $routeid);

        if (Config::Get('DISABLE_BIDS_ON_BID') == true) {
            $bids = SchedulesData::getBids(Auth::$pilot->pilotid);

            # They've got somethin goin on
            if (count($bids) > 0) {
                echo 'Bid exists!';
                return;
            }
        }

        $ret = SchedulesData::AddBid(Auth::$pilot->pilotid, $routeid);
        CodonEvent::Dispatch('bid_added', 'Schedules', $routeid);

        if ($ret == true) {
            echo 'Bid added';
        } else {
            echo 'Already in bids!';
        }
    }
```

But I always get "No Route Passed" meaning the id gets to the jQuery function but doesn't go from there to my module function.

Please help me find out where I'm wrong?

Comment: check your network requests and see if the `id` is been passed or not

Comment: does the anchor tag contain the id when its rendered ?

Comment: @CerlinBoss, how do I do that?

Comment: in chrome, rightclick -> inspect element -> then go to network tab and refresh the page with that tab open

Comment: @dreamweiver the tag contains the id since it passed if I add "?id=$schedule->id "at the end of my "<a href="">"

Comment: add the fail handler `).fail(function(){ 
  // Handle error here
}` to your `$.get`  and see if you get any error . ref : https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Comment: @CerlinBoss. Ok I can see my .js in the inspection and when I click it shows me a windows at the bottom with multiple tabs and one of them is 'response' but I can't tell if the value is actually being passed!!

Comment: check for `Query Sting Parameters` in headers section. Can be found in the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine if you use the newer promise syntax for $.get like so

```
$.get(url+"schedules/addbid?id="+$(this).attr("id")).then(
            function (data) {
                $(id).html(data);
                return false;
        });
```

You can also add a function to be run in case of failure which will help with your debugging like so;

```
$.get(url+"schedules/addbid?id="+$(this).attr("id")).then(
                function(data) {
                    $(id).html(data);
                    return false;
                },function failed(err){
                    console.log(err)
                });
```

Comment: Hi,your solution is working thanks. however another issue is that I want the results(Bid Added message or preferably an image) to be shown at the same page as my template file. Right now the Bid gets Added but it'shown in a different page.

Comment: probably on the server side php